# background text is black when scrolling in the area not initially displayed - android phonegap

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

My phonegap android app adds a black background to my article after scrolling up (if I scroll up of 1 line then text goes up and 1 line has a black backgound and so on; the part that is not displayed inizially gets a black background)

This happens only on samsung G3 not on one tablet.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="content" id="myContent" class="content">
```

CSS:

```
div#myContent{
    width: 100%;
    overflow:scroll;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}
```

How to get rid of it?